# Finding the potential of a vector field

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

What is the potential of this vector field?

$$20\frac{x}{z}i+14\frac{y}{z}j+\Bigl(1−\frac{10x^2+7y^2}{z^2}\Bigr)k$$

I can't seem to get the right answer. I have to type in the answer for our assignment, but I don't get how to do it. what is the answer, and how do I do it?

Comment: What did you do to try and to calculate the potential?

Comment: Have you checked the your field *can* have a potential?

Comment: If you include details of your own attempts, then it’s much more likely that someone can point out where you’re going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for one possibility: if $\vec F$ is a vector field *with some conditions* the potential of $F$ is given by:
$$f(\vec x) = \int_0^1 \vec F(t\vec x)\cdot\vec x\,dt.$$
(in your case you will need "move" this formula)

Alternatively: if your field is $= \nabla f$:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 20\frac{x}{z},
$$
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 14\frac{y}{z},
$$
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \Bigl(1−\frac{10x^2+7y^2}{z^2}\Bigr).
$$